# Magento 2 create new Store email Address

Tags: magento2, email

I want to create a new store email like **Custom Email 3**. As there are two emails already Magento has **Custom 1** and **Custom 2**. I want to add new **Custom 3**. I have tried to find any solution but failed. Any solution / Suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These items are defined via a module's system.xml, in this case `vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` in a composer install version of Magento 2.

To add a new version I would create a new module with a system.xml and then in that new system.xml you can add the new items with the following snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="trans_email">
            <group id="ident_custom3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom Email 3</label>
                <field id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Email</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Address</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Name</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Sender</backend_model>
                    <validate>validate-emailSender</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

I would also consider adding a dependancy on your module to the backend module and config module as the section of the system.xml you are working with is only defined in backend and you are using two models from the config module.

Comment: Thanks @David Will try this

Comment: This should allow you to add the config via the admin. You will of course still need to get that data whenever you want to use it in your code.